# Where can I see Scrum Feature items?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, scrum

In VS 2013, when using Scrum template, there is a New Item called Feature in Team Explorer. When we add Feature, it does not appear in the current sprint (Unfinished work). If Feature is meant to represent something that cannot be done in single sprint, then it is logical for it not to appear under current sprint.

But where can I see features I have added? And is there a place where I can see a more graphical representation of the Features, PBIs and Tasks I have added?

I am using VS2013 Professional and TFS 2013 Express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Features are indeed meant to be larger and need to be decomposed into Product Backlog Items in order to take them into a sprint. On the backlog there is a way to see the link relationship:

[image]

I'm not sure this view exists in the Express edition of TFS. I suspect that it doesn't, as it's part of the "**advanced** agile planning" features.

You can create a work item query that shows the same thing:

[image]

Comment: I am guessing that the images you have posted are from the Visual Studio Online? I can see features, PBI and Tasks online in my account (which is free), so it appears it is available to 'basic agile planning'. Is there some free offline software that would allow me to do the same thing? If there is no free offline access to TFS items, is there some other free software that will allow me to do the same thing, not connected to TFS? Basically I am single developer that would want to learn/experience agile planning.

Comment: The images are generated from Web Access from a locally installed TFS server. You can generate the query from Visual Studio, Team Explorer or Excel (if Team Explorer is installed).